# Python iterate over specific column in csv , and replacing values

Tags: python-3.x, csv

First sorry for my english ;)

I have a problem regarding a csv file. The file contains a lot of col. with a lot of different features. I want to iterate over the col. host_location to get the entries of each row. For each String which contains ("London" or "london") i want to change the string into an binary. So if the string contains "London" or "london" the entry should be 1 , if not 0.

Im familiar with Java, but Python is new for me.

What i know so far with reference to this problem:

i cant change the csv file directly, i have to read it, change the value and write it back to a new file.

My method so far:

```
listings = io.read_csv('../data/playground/neu.csv')

def Change_into_Binaryy():
  listings.loc[listings["host_location"] == ( "London" or 
  "london"),"host_location"] = 1
  listings.to_csv("../data/playground/neu1.csv",index =False)
```

The code is from another question of stackoverflow, and im really not familiar with Python so far. The problem is that i can only use the equal operator and not something like contains in java.

As a result only the entries with the string "London" or "london" are changed to 1. But there are also entries like "London, Uk" that i want to change

In addition i don't know how i can change the remaining entries to 0 , because i don't know how i can combine the .loc with sth. like a if/else construct

I also tried another solution:

```
def Change_into_Binary():

for x in  listings['host_location']:
    if "London" or "london" in x:
        x = 1

    else:
        x = 0

listings.to_csv("../data/playground/neu1.csv",index =False)
```

But also do not work. In this case the entries are not changed.

Thanks for you answers

Comment: did my solution work?

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot to answer, it worked perfectly thanks !

Answer (score 0):

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter


with open('infile.csv', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = DictReader(infile)
    writer = DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        if row['host_location'].capitalize() == 'London':
            row['host_location'] = 1
        else:
            row['host_location'] = 0
        writer.writerow(row)
```